# How to Set the Monitor Configuration on Startup?

Tags: command-line, lubuntu, multiple-monitors

Lubuntu 20.04:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
$
```

I have a laptop with a dock, and two additional monitors plugged into the dock.  Apparently, those monitors still report themselves when soft-powered-off (not "no-signal-standby", but "power-button-off"), so the display manager still thinks I want to use them.  But most of the time, I don't, and I want to leave them off.

Unfortunately, the configuration that it comes up with automatically, has the taskbar on one of those docked monitors.  (which is turned off)  So I *have* to turn it on, to get to the menu, to tell it not to use it.

The procedure is essentially:

- Menu -> Preferences -> LXQt settings -> Monitor settings
  [image]
  Or run `lxqt-config-monitor` in a terminal.
- Settings button
  [image]
- Choose the **Single** option that I've already saved and renamed to that, and Apply
  [image]
  The **Multi_Home** option uses the docked monitors, in the *correct* configuration, but most of the time, I want the **Single**.

I have two startup scripts already: one runs as root, the other as me a few seconds later.  Is there something that I can put in one of those, to apply the **Single** option automatically?

---

My user-level startup script is started by a desktop config file in `~/.config/autostart/`.  Next to it is a `~/.config/autostart/lxqt-config-monitor-autostart.desktop` file that I didn't create, with these contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Comment=Autostart monitor settings for LXQt-config-monitor
Exec=lxqt-config-monitor -l
Name=lxqt-config-monitor-autostart
OnlyShowIn=LXQt
Type=Application
Version=1.0
```

Might that have anything to do with anything?

Comment: You haven't provided your release details... I want them so I know your stack (eg. I'm aware of some issues with Qt 5.12.8 LTS where later fixes were not backported as didn't impact security)... Even if that isn't your used Qt, the release details are useful (they tell me what LXQt you're using!)

Comment: @guiverc Whoops!  Sorry about that.  I'm on a different machine now, so I'll start it back up again and get it.

Comment: @guiverc Fixed, see edit.

Comment: :(  suspected as much.. you are using that LTS release of Qt (LTS releases use the LTS versions of toolkits/libraries). but it may not be the issue; I'll have to explore later on a 20.04 box and see if I can offer something..

Comment: FYI: What I read as your main question "*Is there something that I can put in one of those, to apply the Single option automatically?*" isn't very prominent as the placement of what I've treated as a *minor secondary* question reads as primary given it's placement.. and edit may be in order.  also I get the same behavior on a 20.04 or *focal* install (I won't experiment on that box though; my QA installs of 20.04.3 have been replaced with *impish* already which appears to have the same behavior so I'll play more there later)

Comment: @guiverc Thanks for the tip, but I'm getting a creative block in actually fixing it. My original thought was, "General question in the title, then context, then specific (and possibly XY) question when there's enough foundation to actually understand it." I've been smacked down hard (not just here) for asking a supposedly nonsensical question without that context first, and this format is the result. (I've also been criticized for "not being clear" with this format, but you're the first to say *how*.) I could bold the later question in-place, but it still keeps a troublesome format overall.